# How does Data flow (via Bluetooth) until it reaches its destination?

Tags: bluetooth

I am currently looking through a lot of documentation, to solve this on my own, but it would be a great help, to exclude the irrelevant paths.

So, this is the scenario, which I am trying to visualize the flow of data for:

- two identical CSR04 BT-Modules are connected through SPP
- both are connected by USB to a host computer
- while one of them is sending data, it is of interest how this data travels to reach the other Module

Now, this is what I have so far:

1. the Radio-Layer of the receiving BT-Module is picking up data
2. the data is passed through the BT-layers up to the SPP-layer
3. the data is buffered by the BT-Module
4. the data is passed through USB to the host
5. the host buffers this data into the buffer of a virtual serial port
6. an application reads out this buffered data

My gaps are between 3 and 4 and between 4 and 5. I am not quite sure, how the SPP-Layer is passing its data, so that the host can buffer it.

Is this path of data correct or am I missing here something? If so, what? And how does the SPP-Layer pass the data to the USB connected host?

Answer (score 0):

The SPP layer doesn't run on the BT module.  The BT module pushes data to the host over USB at the HCI layer.  SPP layer is done by drivers on your PC which take HCI data from the BT module and present a regular serial port interface on the other side for applications on PC.